# Composer satis, time to build private packages

Tags: composer-php, satis

I have many private repositories at Bitbucket, there are about 100 repo's (+/-). Time to build them by `php bin/satis build` takes a long time, somewhere about 3 minutes. How can i refresh one repository or optimize time of building. Because i saw some satis configuration, where `config.json` file contain more than 4000 repositories. I can not imagine how many time need to build all of this.

Answer (score 3):

The more private repos you have, the longer Satis will need to build the static archive.

- reduce the number of packages, if possible
- configure Satis to provide only some and not all versions of a repo

  - switch from `"require-all": true` to manually listing the repos and specific versions (beware: this is tedious to maintain, but fast)
- configure Satis to maybe `skip-dev`, when generating `archives` (to skip branches)
- do you need archives at all or only source? if only source, disable archive generation
- add Satis to a cronjob, the first run takes a while, after that the cache is used
- with repo count of 100+, i would suggest to setup and switch to a private Packagist server
- Satis does not yet support "selective update of repos".
    It's a long standing issue / feature request, see https://github.com/composer/satis/issues/40

Comment: Thnx @Jens A. Koch. If someone want to try something more faster than composer satis, i've done my project, which written on golang [github.com/johnnywidth/combozer](https://github.com/johnnywidth/combozer)